# What is the difference between "Zu" and "Auf" in these sentences?

Tags: difference, preposition

What is the difference between

> Ich blickte **zu** Boden

and

> Ich blickte **auf** Boden

?

Answer (score 14):

*Zu Boden* simply means that your head was was tilted towards the floor, e.g. due to shyness. *Auf den Boden* (the article can't be omitted here) would be used for looking at the carpet, searching for something you have accidentally dropped or spilled on it, or anything placed there.

Comment: Actually the 2nd sentence isn't technically wrong. Just as you can say "Ich blickte auf Türme", without specifying an article. Example usage: "Ich driftete Äonen durch den Weltraum, leere Weite überall, bis ich auf einem Planeten notlandete. Ich traute meinen Augen kaum: Ich blickte auf Boden." or sth like that. (Although that changes the meaning)

Comment: "Ich blicke auf *singular_noun*" is incorrect.
"Ich blicke auf *plural_noun*" is correct.
Ich blicke auf *article singular_noun* is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the most conspicuous difference is, that one sentence is correct and the other is wrong:

> *correct:* Ich blickte **zu** Boden.
> *wrong:* Ich blickte **auf** Boden.

But you can turn the second sentence into a correct sentence by adding an article:

> *correct:* Ich blickte **auf den** Boden.

---

### zu Boden

The fixed phrase *»zu Boden«* just means a movement and the direction of this movement is downwards (*»down to the ground«*):

> Bei der Flucht wurden einige Menschen **zu Boden** getrampelt.
> <sup>During the escape, some people were trampled **to the ground.**</sup>
>
> Werft ihn zu Boden!
> <sup>Throw him **to the floor!**</sup>
>
> Nach einem hefigen Treffer ging der Boxer **zu Boden.**
> <sup>After a fierce hit the boxer kissed the dust. (literal: ... the boxer went **to the ground.**)</sup>

But you can also use this phrase to describe a movement of somebodies eyes:

> Sie blickte verschämt **zu Boden.**
> <sup>Bashfully she lowered her gaze. (Literal: She looked bashfully **to the ground.**)</sup>

---

### auf den Boden

There is no similar fixed Phrase *»<del>auf Boden</del>«.* But you still can use the preposition *»auf«* together with the noun *»Boden«,* but if you do so, you also have to use an article between both words. And since the preposition *»zu«* wants dative case, and because there is only one ground (i.e. singular), and because *»Boden«* is a masculine noun, the correct article is *»den«: »auf **den** Boden«.*

Now the meaning is a movement whose target is the ground. This is a very subtile difference to the movement described before which was a movement in a direction. Now it's a movement that ends at a place. In German this is not the same, and you can see that also in English there is a difference:

> zu Boden = movement **to** the ground
> auf den Boden = movement that ends **on** the ground

Here are examples:

> Irene legte sich **auf den Boden.**
> <sup>Irene lay down **on the ground.**</sup>
>
> Er warf sich voller Demut vor dem König **auf den Boden.**
> <sup>He threw himself **on the ground** before the king with humility.</sup>
>
> Der Küchenjunge ließ ein Ei **auf den Boden** fallen.
> <sup>The kitchen boy dropped an egg **on the floor.**</sup>

In the context of looking somewhere, you can also look at the ground:

> Der Inspektor blickte nur kurz **auf den Boden** und sah sofort die Fußspuren.
> <sup>The inspector looked **at the ground** only for a moment and immediately saw the footprints.</sup>

Comment: "And since the preposition »zu« wants dative case...": I think you confused yourself! You are talking about »auf« here, not »zu«; and »den« is accusative, not dative.