# What is the difference between zu and auf when going to an event?

Tags: difference, preposition

According to my notes, you'd use *zu* when you're going to an event. For example:

> *Wir gehen zu einer Party.* – "We're going to a party."
> *Ich gehe zu einer Hochzeit.* – "I'm going to a wedding."

But the DWDS has many examples where *auf* is used instead:

> *Wir gehen auf eine Party.* – "We're going to a party."
> *Ich gehe auf eine Hochzeit.* – "I'm going to a wedding."

In fact there is one case where both versions are given for the same line:

> Ich gehe heute zu/auf eine(r) Hochzeit. (From "Shameless" Three Boys, 2011)

1. What is the difference, if any, in meaning between the two versions? I gather it depends on the verb, for example with ''fahren'' you'd always use ''zu''. But that makes sense since you might be driving to the party without actually taking part; maybe you're giving someone a ride. But ''kommen'' seems to favor ''auf''.
2. I'm not familiar with this meaning of *auf*, so is this part of a larger pattern or is it just random? I'm thinking it's covered under [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auf) definition I.2.d): "*bezeichnet die Teilnahme an etw.*" This would imply that using *auf* implies a degree of participation and engagement which is missing from *zu*. Is that correct?

Related: [What is the difference between "Zu" and "Auf" in these sentences?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65829/43989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some overlapping issue here:

For locations there is a difference between *zum* and *in*: *Ich gehe zum Bahnhof* does not imply you enter the building, similarly *ich gehe zur Schule* may just indicate a pupil and does not imply, that the the speaker is there or on her/his way towards school.

All of your examples seem to fall under the [DWDS: auf](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auf#d-1-1-3) meaning I/1/c, participation at some event, since you probably want to interact with other guests.

While this is also covered by [DWDS: zu](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zu) meaning I/1/b *specifies direction with the intent to participate*, I notice a certain emphasis on the location aspect in the definition.

I have to mention the counter-example: *Ich gehe zum Frühschoppen*. It is pretty obvious, that one wants to enter the pub and drink as well as talk to others in whatever ratio.

I observe, that in classical music one would more likely use *ich gehe in ein/zu einem Konzert* (or *in eine/zu einer Opernaufführung*) and there is not much interaction typically, you take your seat, listen and hopefully enjoy and applaud afterwards. For pop and rock bands *auf ein Konzert gehen* is more frequently used, and I wonder, if that is due to the event character, as dancing, singing along, clapping the rhythm and waving your lighter?

My summary: *zu* / *auf* may not be entirely exchangeable, but the difference is difficult to decide and dependent on context.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that it's not only context, but regional differences or even personal preference. I see *Frühschoppen* (which I'm hearing about for the first time) as more of an activity than an event, the difference being that one is routine or habit and one a deviation from routine. I understand that there is a lot of grey area in preposition choice, but there are lighter greys and darker grays and it's nice to know where those are.

Comment: PS. I wonder if people didn't clap, dance, etc. when Mozart was performing a concert, back when "classical music" was just "music".

Answer (score 2):

If one says *Ich gehe auf eine Party* this means that s/he will not only go to a party but also attend it. One would usually not say this if s/he goes to a party to e.g. pick someone up or just glance at it and go home.

On the other hand, *Ich gehe zur Party* can be used if someone goes to a party, but without staying there for a while.

In most cases, the sentences will have the same meaning. But there are cases when the meaning can differ, as explained above.

Comment: I thought this is also a regional thing? Like "Auf Schalke"? Or going "zur Arbeit" vs. "auf Arbeit" (more in the south?) ? Not that sure about it.

Comment: This more or less confirms what I was thinking. It seems to be more a matter of emphasis than meaning; use *zu* to emphasize that you're appearing at the location and *auf* to emphasize that you're participating

Comment: @Shegit Brahm: I can't find *Auf Schalke* in the references I normally use. It doesn't help that Schalke is the name of a sports club and Schalk is the name of some people. Is it regional dialect?

Comment: *Auf Schalke* is strictly regional (*Ruhrdeutsch*). *Auf eine Party gehen* is Standard German.

Comment: @RDBury: I'm talking about this discussion: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ich-gehe-zur-in-auf-an-die-arbeit.2905201/ or https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/10661/sbj/was-ist-richtig-auf-arbeit-fahren-oder-zur-arbeit-fahren/ So, yes, "Auf Schalke" might be too specific, yet it has a regional language root. Maybe "Arbeit" is the very special and only event that is known with different prepositions and still the same meaning.